# Godot distance between 3d and 2d nodes

Tags: 2d, 3d, godot

Godot has the `distance_to` methods for `Vector3` and `Vector2` but what would be the best way to get the distance from a 3d node to a 2d node? For example, I'm looking to see how far away the 3d kinematic body is from a 2d text label.

Currently, I'm trying something like:

```
var player_global_origin = player.global_transform.origin
var player_vec2 = Vector2(player_global_origin.z, player_global_origin.x)

var distance_to_label = player_vec2.distance_to(label.get_global_transform().origin)
```

Which seems to work ok when just moving forwards and backwards but it feels like it's easy to break.

Comment: Do you want the distance *on screen* (which depends on the 3D camera)?

Comment: @Theraot I think so. I just need to change the size of the text depending on the distance of the player.

Comment: If the label is tied to something in the world (e.g. it represent what an NPC says), you can use the position of that something in the world to compute the distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the position of a 3D object *on screen*, you can do the following:

```
var position_2d = get_viewport().get_camera().unproject_position(position_3d)
```

That is, we use the camera projection to get the 3D position into screen coordinates with [`Camera.unproject_position`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_camera.html#class-camera-method-unproject-position) which takes a `Vector3` and returns `Vector2`. *Why is that unproject and not project? Don't know.*

However, we need a `Camera` to do that. Luckily [`Viewport.get_camera`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_viewport.html#class-viewport-method-get-camera) returns the current 3D `Camera`.  *Why is there not a 2D counterpart? Don't know.*

And of course, to use `get_camera` we need a `Viewport`. We can get the `Viewport` the node belongs to with [`Node.get_viewport`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-method-get-viewport).

---

Of course, once you have the 2D position on the screen, you can use `distance_to` to find the distance to any `Control` on the screen, or whatever you need.

You can also use this to have a control follow a 3D object. This example is from the official documentation:

```
control.visible = not get_viewport().get_camera().is_position_behind(global_transform.origin)
control.rect_position = get_viewport().get_camera().unproject_position(global_transform.origin)
```